# Memory and Perf comparison of BigInt vs Byte array in scala

Tags: java, scala, ipv6, biginteger, inetaddress

I have to use a type that can hole Ipv4 and Ipv6 addresses in memory efficient manner (in scala). As well as they should be performant. The two options I see are, using the scala BigInt type or a byte array. What the memory/perf hit in both cases?

Comment: That's a very broad question and without knowing what you want to do with those it's hard to answer. What research did you do so far? Do you _really_ run into memory issues or do you just assume you could? How many addresses are you talking about?

Comment: Using them as string we have ran into memory issues. We are processign flows and the numbers reach to billion, so sotring should be very efficient. At the same time look ups are made against maps and whether an ip falls betwen two IPs etc are computed, so they should be fast as well. Till now we had used Long as uint is not there in scala, and now we are trying to incorporate ipv6 as well.

Comment: Hmm you could have a look at `InetAddress` and `Inet6Address` and even if those aren't usable for you (they might have too many additional fields that take up memory) you should at least be able to duplicate the relevant parts in a custom class that uses byte arrays internally.

Comment: I am using InetAdress apis to convert to byte array and convert back to string. Challenge is implementing utils like wher given a ip, telling if that falls between other 2 ips or not (All are represented as byte array). BigInt makes is simpler.

Comment: Well, comparing byte arrays shouldn't be too hard, at least if they have the same length: If I'm not mistaken, you'd just have to compare the elements one by one until you find one that differs (handling the unsigned nature of `byte` adds a little complexity though).

Comment: Not knowing Scala, I guess that plain arrays are less clobbered by extras than BigIntegers, i.e. they are probably more memory and time efficient. If the sole reason to use BigIntegers would be equality comparison, that should be quite simple for arrays too, especially if they are of a fixed size. See what @Thomas wrote.

Answer (score 0):

BigInteger in Java takes `5 * 4 bytes` for 4 `int` fields plus `int` array. BigInt from Scala is just wrapper over BigInteger so it would be similar. So using `Byte` array would definitely take less place.

I might also consider using type aliases with companion object and implicit extensions to keep type safety and rich API without additional overhead (it will still the same amount of space as `Array[Byte]`.

```
trait IP

type IPv4 = Array[Byte] with IP //adding "with IP" would make sure compiler won't accept plain Array[Byte] when type IPv4 is needed

type IPv6 = Array[Byte] with IP

object IPv4 { //create similar for IPv6

  def apply(ip: String) = {
    ip.split("\\.").map(_.toByte).asInstanceOf[IPv4] //you can create IPv4("127.0.0.1")
  }

  object Implicits {
    implicit class RichIPv4(ip: IPv4) {
        def show(): String = ip.map(_.toString).mkString(".") //add method to show as string
      def verify(): Boolean = ??? //additional methods
    }
  }

}

import IPV4.Implicits._

def printIP(ip: IPv4) = println(ip.show) //Will only accept arrays created by IPv4.apply

printIP(IPv4("127.0.0.1")) //ok
printIP(Array[Byte](127,0,0,1)) //won't compile
```

Alternatively, you should take a look at the great library [scala-newtype](https://github.com/estatico/scala-newtype), which does similar things but without additional boilerplate.